# Difference between different jenkins pipeline plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on to setup regression for one of my project through jenkins. I am new to jenkins and kind of confused with so many available pipeline plugins. To name a few:

1. [Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin)
2. [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin)
3. [Delivery Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin)

They all seem same to me. Can anyone help me decide when to use which plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the idea is the same, they are very different in the way how you implement a deployment pipeline.

Long story short: use the [Pipeline plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator), which is the "new" way and officially supported by the Jenkins team / Cloudbees and used by a huge community (see also the number of questions for [jenkins-pipeline](/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline)).

This allows you to define your pipeline as code following the *Infrastructure as Code* paradigm.

You can find the documentation for pipelines at https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/.

Comment: about `which is the "new" way and officially supported by the Jenkins team / Cloudbees` could you share an official link about that information or decision?

Comment: Clarification: Pipeline plugin is what you will use to actually create the logic. The Delivery Pipeline plugin is actively maintained plugin that only provides visualization on top of this. The purpose of that plugin is to provide delivery pipeline visualization suitable for information radiators such as big screens. The Build pipeline plugin also provides visualization, however it is limited to traditional Jenkins jobs, e.g. FreeStyle and might not be actively maintained, the latest release being a year ago according to the Jenkins plugin site.