# What is the difference between Build pipeline and Delivery pipeline in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I would appreciate if anyone could briefly point out what the difference between Build and Delivery pipelines in Jenkins? Are they the same with different producers?

Comment: Please refer another post published in this forum. This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48679744/difference-between-different-jenkins-pipeline-plugin

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a depth knowledge of both plugin but from my experience, the subtle difference between the Delivery Pipeline Plugin and Build Pipeline Plugin is that the first one allows you to use Freestyle Jobs and Pipeline Jobs while the second one only allows Freestyle Jobs.

So if you're using Shared Libs for your pipelines and want to use any of this plugins to have an overview of downstream and upstream Jobs you should definitely go for Delivery pipeline plugin

Build Pipeline Plugin:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-pipeline-plugin/

Delivery Pipeline Plugin:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/delivery-pipeline-plugin/